# "What time it starts?" or "What time does it start?"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is correct or significantly better?

> a) "What time the train leaves?"

or

> b) What time **does** the train leave?"

Comment: "What time does it start" is the correct way, but I cant explain why

Comment: @Chillin' thank you. I fixed my question body which previously had an incorrect example.

Comment: Please don't phrase your question as "which is correct/better?", as these are interpreted as "proofreading" requests, which are off-topic. Instead, specify your concern and tell us why it's concerning. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in English, questions require [inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions). So, "What time does it start?" and "What time does the train leave?" are correct, and "What time it starts?" and "What time the train leaves?" are not correct.

(The main exception is that inversion is not used when a *wh*-word is the subject of the question. For example, if we want to ask for the identity of the passenger of a train, we say "Who is on the train?", not "Is who on the train?")

Comment: Thank you. i believe the reference proves you correct; so accepting. If any other answers outweigh your reasoning, I may reconsider. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct structure of interrogative sentences in present simple tense is:

```
Do / does + pronoun / noun + verb?
```

or

```
Question word + do / does + pronoun / noun + verb?
```

So regarding to your question, the second option is the correct choice:

> "What time **does** the train leave?"

Though, in the spoken language you can hear many people who omit the auxiliary verb do/does, but it is not according to the grammar rules.

For further explanation and practice, see [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple).